# Getting "undefined" when trying to post with EXPRESS on SQL database?

Tags: sql, node.js, express

(still a beginner with sql and express)

I am trying to make a post request on my SQL database with express. When I try posting with Postman, I get a "TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined".

Here's the code:

```
    app.post('/getperipherals', (req, res) => {
    let product = {
        product_name: req.body.product_name,
        product_type: req.body.product_type,
        product_brand: req.body.product_brand,
        product_description: req.body.product_description,
        product_url: req.body.product_url,
    };
    let sql = `INSERT INTO users (product_name, product_type, product_brand, product_description, product_url, register_date) values ('?', '?', '?', '?','?', now())`;
    let query = db.query(sql, product, (err, result) => {
        if(err) throw err;
        res.send(result)
    })
})
```

This is what my request looks like on postman:

```
{
"product_name": "Imprimante TEST",
"product_type": "printer", 
"product_brand": "Marque TEST",
"product_description": "This is a POST test", 
"product_url": "https://i.imgur.com/RwvdTpV.png" 
}
```

( a POST request, with my custom route -which is working-)

Comment: http://idownvotedbecau.se/imageofcode

Comment: Are you sure that `req` has a `body` property? I’ve only done very little with express but I remember this being an issue. What hapens when you `console.log(req)`?

Comment: @mspi it's what I've found on https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/nodejs-req-object-in-expressjs   => " The req.body object allows you to access data in a string or JSON object from the client side. You generally use the req.body object to receive data through POST and PUT requests in the Express server."

Comment: @Guillaume-G9 Sure, but it’s pretty much the only problem I can think of that matches the error you’re getting based on the code you posted. What I’m saying is try to debug your code before you post a question, and if you did, write what you have found out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
app.post('/getperipherals', (req, res) => {
    let {product_name,product_type,product_brand,product_description,product_url } = req.body;
    let sql = `INSERT INTO users (product_name, product_type, product_brand, product_description, product_url, register_date) values (product_name,product_type,product_brand,product_description,product_url, now())`;
    let query = db.query(sql, product, (err, result) => {
        if(err) throw err;
        return res.send(result)
    });
});
```

Try this out let me know if it work or not for you

Comment: Thanks for this answer! It didn't solve my problem, but it helped me getting an idea of what was wrong: first of all, I had placed the "const app = express()" at the end and that's what caused the undefined. But then I got an error about the SQL syntax where Express removed all underscores in the request. I tried escaping it with \ and with [] but it still didn't work.

Comment: That's great :) I'm glad you figured out the problem and solved it.

Answer (score 0):

**EDIT**

Finally found a way to get it to work: I used `INSERT INTO SET`

```
app.post('/getperipherals', (req, res) => {
  let product = {
    product_name: req.body.product_name,
    product_type: req.body.product_type,
    product_brand: req.body.product_brand,
    product_description: req.body.product_description,
    product_url: req.body.product_url,
  };

  let sql = "INSERT INTO peripherals SET ?";
  let query = db.query(sql, product, (err, result) => {
    if(err) throw err;
    return res.send(result)
  });
});
```